# Tab order with paper input and own element

Tags: polymer, accessibility

I have made my own "date" input which consists of a paperinput, the pikaday date picker and a date validator (also my own).  The reason for this is I have a requirement to both allow "vague" dates (if someone types 4 digits with a value between 1901 and 2050 that means any time in a specific year) and complex other rules so 2811 means 20th November current year (I am british so working with dd/mm/yy - but system I am replacing doesn't need the user to enter the / character).

I have a form with two paper-input fields followed by my date field.  Tabbing moves nicely between them until I tab away from my special element, when for one tab nothing is selected and then the next tab the next field is selected.

I put some code on the blur event of my date elements paper input, and the did a `var test = document.activeElement;` in the event handler.  The result of this is the body element from my page.

How do I make the tab order play nicely?

Comment: URL? Also, `blur` kills any focus, it does not move focus.

Comment: No url this will be an internal private application. I am not calling the elements blur function, I am listening for the blur event.

Comment: If I could see the page I might be able to identify where the tab is going. I am not a Polymer dev, so I cannot speculate. Try adding this CSS and see if it highlights anything on the missing tab. If not, then yeah, would need to see some kind of page. The CSS: `*:focus,a:focus{outline:2px dotted #00f !important;box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(255,255,255,.75) !important;}`

Comment: I found what was happening.  The date field triggered pikaday to create a date picker which had some button elements in it.  On blur, the picker was hidden, but by then it had already received the tab, so as it disappeared body became the active element.  Since I already had a non standard version to support pikaday working nicely with polymer element, I also changed it to add tabindex="-1" attributes on the buttons in the picker as I don't want/need keyboard support on the picker (part of my special input is special interpretation of keyboard input in the date field).  This fixed the issue

Comment: Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in the comment under the question, the pikaday date picker had received the tab on the blur, but was then immediately hidden.  This left the tab with the body.  I changed the various buttons on the picker to have tabindex="-1" added as the picker is created.  This resolved the problem